# Can one convert a MySQL connection to a PDO connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I work on a app which has only one way to get a working DB connection: a function that returns a MySQL connection resource.

Is there any way for me to convert that MySQL connection to a PDO MySQL connection?

I don't have access to the MySQL server in any other way, no username, password, nothing. I can't see/get the file with the function in it, either. I might be able to, later, but still, I'd like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - that's impossible. PDO and the ext/mysql are two completely different components to access a MySQL server.

Without username, password, host (can be retrieved by using `string mysql_get_host_info  ([ resource $link_identifier  ] )` and database name (can be retrieved by looking at a list of databases on the server with `resource mysql_list_dbs  ([ resource $link_identifier  ] )`), you won't be able to connect to the server with any other method than the given one. It's impossible to read the username and/or password from a given ext/mysql resource.